# Certificate verify failed using cygwin python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, https, cygwin

I have been using a my own CA for local https sites. When I started using cygwin python 3.8, I got the error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)
```

But wget to the same url works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.8 came with certifi, which has its own certificate store in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

I grabbed the local CA from the standard place

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

and appended it to the certifi cacert.pem.

This sorts out the CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.